# Introduction to flag manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, lie-groups, complex-geometry

What is a good self-contained introduction to the geometry of complex flag manifolds?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean by "geometry", e.g., existence of an Einstein-Kaehler metric (in which case _Einstein Manifolds_, by Besse, comes to mind), or the homogeneous structure, or...? Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I hope to find something includes all what you mentioned. But if i find something deals with stein structures on flag manifolds that would be great too :)